# Can't load serverSocket class Networking two Air Applications

Tags: air, flash-builder

I'm trying to make a Air server send files that server located on another computer on a local network and have then saved.  All docs I have found require the serverSocket class.

I'm using FlashBuilder4(Air is selected as project) and when I go to import:
"import flash.net.ServerSocket;"
Socket is there but ServerSocket is not, am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED** 
I was running Flashbuilder 4 with Air SDK 1.x.x Air SDK need to be updated to AirSDK2.0

Instructions to update are here:
http://www.adobe.com/support/documentation/en/air/2/releasenotes_developers.html#h